# index of the subfactor

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $N\subset M$ is an inclusion of type II$_1$ factors, Jones define the index $[M:N]$.

If $N$ is the type II subfactor of the type III factor $M$. How to define $[M:N]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the index of an inclusion of factors depends on the conditional expectation (if it exists). There is the notion of *minimal index*, but this does no necessarily coincide with the Jones index for $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor inclusions.

In your case, if $E\colon M\to N$ is a normal conditional expectation, then
$$
\mathrm{Ind}(E)=\inf\{\lambda\geq 0\mid \lambda E(x)\geq x\text{ for all }x\in M_+\}.
$$
This version of the index is called the Pimsner-Popa index. There is another definition that relies on spatial derivatives and operator-valued weights, which coincides with the Pimsner-Popa index in this case. However, it is more complicated to spell out. A detailed account of index theory beyond the type $\mathrm{II}_1$ case is given in these lecture notes by Kosaki: https://pages.uoregon.edu/njp/lec-f.pdf.

Comment: Thanks. But in most theorems, the author only dicsuss the  index of $E$ is finite. If $M$ and $N$ are different types, the index may be infinite. I wonder whether there exist some pepers concerning the infinite index.